# UPnP and SOAP to router

Tags: xml, bash, curl, soap, upnp

I am trying to make call for action on my router.

Here is the specification about service:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                                                      
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">                                                                                                             
        <specVersion>                                                                                                                                      
                <major>1</major>                                                                                                                           
                <minor>0</minor>                                                                                                                           
        </specVersion>                                                                                                                                     
        <device>                                                                                                                                           
                <deviceType>urn:schemas-wifialliance-org:device:WFADevice:1</deviceType>                                                                   
                <friendlyName>WFADevice</friendlyName>
                <manufacturer>Broadcom Corporation</manufacturer>
                <manufacturerURL>http://www.broadcom.com</manufacturerURL>
                <modelDescription>Wireless Device</modelDescription>
                <modelName>WPS</modelName>
                <modelNumber>X1</modelNumber>
                <serialNumber>0000001</serialNumber>
                <UDN>uuid:9b317afe-7404-5ecd-d051-fd3d1733cbee</UDN>
                <serviceList>
                        <service>
                                <serviceType>urn:schemas-wifialliance-org:service:WFAWLANConfig:1</serviceType>
                                <serviceId>urn:wifialliance-org:serviceId:WFAWLANConfig1</serviceId>
                                <SCPDURL>/x_wfawlanconfig.xml</SCPDURL>
                                <controlURL>/control?WFAWLANConfig</controlURL>
                                <eventSubURL>/event?WFAWLANConfig</eventSubURL>
                        </service>
                </serviceList>
        </device>
</root>
```

One of the actions i am trying to make a request to is called `GetDeviceInfo`:

```xml
<action>
    <name>GetDeviceInfo</name>
        <argumentList>
            <argument>
                <name>NewDeviceInfo</name>
                <direction>out</direction>
                <relatedStateVariable>DeviceInfo</relatedStateVariable>
            </argument>
        </argumentList>
</action>
```

Here it is how i am making request:

```sh
$ curl 'http://192.168.0.1:1900/control?WFAWLANConfig' \
-X 'POST' \
-H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"' \
-H 'SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-wifialliance-org:service:WFAWLANConfig:1#GetDeviceInfo"' \
-d '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding">
<s:Body>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'
```

and I am getting:

> ```
> HTTP1.1 400 Bad Request
> Content-Type: text/xml
>
> <title>400 Bad Request</title><body>400 Bad Request</body>
> ```

Can you help me to provide the valid request as i am not very familiar with SOAP and UPnP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself, all I had to change was adding line below inside `<s:Body>`:
`<u:GetDeviceInfo xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:serviceType:v">
</u:GetDeviceInfo>`

Comment: yo mate i almost have the same device as you but the response is in bin.base64 ... how do i read that ?